# Insufficient Installation History in facebook advert

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-ads-api

**We found 1 error. Insufficient Installation History: Your account does not have enough install history to start using billing event for mobile app install ads. Please visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/cost-per-action-ads/ to learn more.**

I got above error in facebook advert page. I am new on this please help me.
Thnxx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When your account/app is new, it is usually not allowed to use CPA bidding (optimization goal and billing event set to `APP_INSTALLS`). You'll need to use impressions or clicks based bidding first and get a few installs that way. Then you can switch to CPA.

There is no official info about the amount of installs, but when you get over 1000, it's usually enough. The number is also tied to account where the ads are created, so you may be allowed to promote your app for installs on one account, while another account is not allowed to do that for the same app yet.

Facebook has a tool called [App Ads Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/), where you can check what types of bidding are available for your app and account.

---

Here's the relevant part from FB docs at the url mentioned in your error message

> You will not be able to buy CPA for mobile app installs unless you have already reported back some installs and your account id-app id-mobile store trio has been deemed non-fraudulent. In the meantime, your ad creation call will fail.

Comment: I updated the answer with more info on installs amount and link to tool where you can check eglibility to use various bidding types for your app

Comment: So do I have to get the installs from running the facebook CPC ads? If I got 10,000 organic installs wouldn't that count?

Comment: Any new updates , I've made about 5K paid installs through facebook. Still can't use CPA bid.

Comment: Is this a "Facebook doesn't care about the little guy" / "puts little guy at huge disadvantage" kind of thing? They provide no clear min.